# Build a protobuf object in haskell with optional fields

Tags: haskell, protocol-buffers

I am building a PB object in Haskell and I do not want to specify optional fields.  Is this possible?

In the very simplest case, I have a header field that has a `failure_message` that I want empty in most cases.  I have some code where a worker task responds with an OK status:

```
        let repMsg = ProtoMsg.WorkerResponse.WorkerResponse {
            header = ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.ReqResponse {
                ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK,
                failure_message = Nothing
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to set all unspecified fields to Nothing some how?  In this case it's not so bad, but when there are more optional fields it gets annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a record value that has the fields you want already set and then update that record.

```hs
noFailureMsg = ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.ReqResponse {
            failure_message = Nothing
        }

let repMsg = ProtoMsg.WorkerResponse.WorkerResponse {
    header = noFailureMsg {
        ProtoMsg.ReqResponse.status = Just ProtoMsg.Status.OK
    }
}
```

I'm not completely sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is definitely an improvement.  I am mostly wondering if there are some flags I can set, or tricks I can use so `Nothing` is used on unspecified fields.  I am new to Haskell so I don't know of any.  It's annoying to build messages that have 10 different fields, only 1 of which is set.